# HTTP GET | POST from Serverless give timeout error and does not return anything

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, node-https

I am using aws serverless mongodb template which works fine with mongodb queries and other local processing
I want make http request to get some data for that i tried. http/http/axios/request

But it just returns me following timeout error

```
{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}
```

Following is my last tried code.

```
const util = require('../../lib/util')
// const UserModel = require('../../schema/User');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

module.exports = async (event) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    return util.bind(json)
  } catch (error) {
    return util.bind(error)
  }
}
```

Similarly API sdk's like paypal and razorpay also become unresponsive wile using.
is this problem with aws settings or nodejs code?

Thanks in advance.

> Above code works fine on serverless offline

Comment: Are you running lambda in VPC?

Comment: Nope not in VPC @jellycsc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per AWS all the lambdas has only incoming connection. lambda can not call any http for us. for that we need to have NAT Gateway.
using NAT Gateway your lambda/serverless will get internet access and it can make outgoing http calls.

Comment: You only need NAT if you are running lambdas in private subnet.